Automating using pywinauto throws not enough rights error even with admin access
I am working on some automation in windows with win32 api where I need to do a series of task when user clicks a button in my app. This series of tasks are always same and needs separate processing thus I am making a thread from my kivy app to execute these tasks. This thread is responsible for connecting to the windows app I am automating and performing actions into it.
All of this is implemented and working correctly as we expect. But sometimes I don't know why, when user clicks the button and the thread tries to automate the app using pywinauto it gives the error: Not enough rights to use EM_REPLACESEL message/function for target process (to resolve it run the script as Administrator). But I am already running my app in Admin mode and the app (in the same run/without restart) was able to connect to the app2 (the app I am automating) and execute the same functions in it.
I don't know why this issue occurs and can't reproduce it as it is random and sometimes occurs after tens of cycles of connecting and executing tasks in app2. So I am just implementing a reconnect and retry functionality for my script, but want to know why this might be occurring so I am able to work on the actual issue and resolve it. Does anyone has any idea why this might be occurring?

Just to make sure... If you logged in as admin user, it doesn't mean the script runs in privileged mode. Right click on the script or cmd.exe and choose option "Run as Administrator". If UAC is enabled, you will be asked for manual confirmation, if UAC is disabled in OS settings, no confirmation needed.

@VasilyRyabov yes, I am sure I am running as an Admin because like I mentioned that the script is working multiple times correctly before throwing error and the App2 which I am automating needs admin access. Also I have wrote a function to explicitly check if my app is in admin mode before starting any processing. And I am also making build of my app in pyinstaller using --uac-admin flag so that it automatically launches in admin mode (and avoid doing the right click and Run as Admin).

Wow! This becomes very interesting. The first such case in the whole history of package. You can take a look at pywinauto/handleprops.py#L310 function has_enough_privileges. It may help to make smaller reproducer or better understand the problem.

@VasilyRyabov thanks, I guess the issue I am facing is because of either my app or the thread I am making on button click is losing admin privilege after 12-16 hours or so. I am trying to make my app work for multiple days in a row without restart because it is being used in a manufacturing site, but this is causing some issues in it. I will try to use the has_enough_privileges to check my privileges and would share results but it might take sometime because of weekend and the error itself taking 16 hours to reproduce.

Sure. Please pay attention if the process is possibly restarted or spawned child process or goes to some unusual state or doesn't respond for some time. Because if OpenProcess function fails, it means something wrong with the process. If it doesn't respond, try app.wait_cpu_usage_lower() playing with its params.

@VasilyRyabov just to make sure that we are supposed to provide the proccess id of the app we are trying to automate in the has_enough_privileges right? I have wrote this code
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(path=app_path)
has_privilege = handleprops.has_enough_privileges(app.process)
to check privilege of the app and am trying to regenerate the issue I mentioned here, but looking at the example in pywinauto github repo, I am not sure that which process id I am supposed to pass here. So can you give some idea about this?

app.process is the right process ID. Because window messages are sent exactly to this process by "win32" backend.

Okay, thanks. I will try to generate the error then.
